# jQuery - autcomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I downloaded this plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/

I write this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtStoryTags').autocomplete('@Url.Action("GetTags", "Thread")', { dataType: 'json',
        parse: function (data) {
            var rows = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].Name, result: data[i].Name };
            }
            return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function (row) {
            return row.Name;
        },
        delay: 40,
        autofill: true,
        selectFirst: false,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: ";"
    });
});
```

And the Json result is:

```
[{"TagID":2,"Name":"tag1","Weight":4},{"TagID":4,"Name":"tag2","Weight":1},
```

Until this point it's fine.
But when I try to use autocomplete I get in result:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Well that's not expect result.
The question is, what's wrong about that client script ? I'm pretty sure the problem lays here, just don't know exactly where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing but

```
formatItem: function (row) {
   return row.Name;
},
```

...looks wrong to me. The 'rows' you provide the plugin have `data`, `value` and `result` fields, but no `Name` field.

Comment: Just checked it, and it's not the case, unfortunetly.

Comment: @Lukasz Baran: I looked that the source code for the plugin you linked to. It makes no reference to either a 'parse' function or a 'formatItem' function. Are you sure you have the right plugin?

Comment: O, you are right. There are sevral plugins of exactly same name, and I've been misslead by  this.